# What are allowed values of the `display` property for a flex-item? (layout of flex-item’s children is irrelevant)

Tags: css, flexbox

All children of a flex container (designated by `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`) are automatically made flex items. There is no display property for a flex item; instead, we set it to some other value depending on how we want the children of the flex item to be laid out.

So, if I set `display` to X value on Y element (taking into account that the Y participates in a flex context, that is Y is a flex-item) can I be sure that I will always get the flex-item that behaves (in this formatting context, in the flex container) like a block-level element?

(In other words, the Y participates in a block formatting context regardless of whether X=block/inline/table-cell/inline-grid/…etc , right?)

- X – non-block value
- Y – flex-item, html element

This:

```
<div id="flex-container" style="display:flex">
    <div id="flex-item" style="display: inline;">item</div>
</div>
```

equals to this (without any side effects)

```
<div id="flex-container" style="display:flex">
    <div id="flex-item" style="display: block;">item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only condition for being a [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) is being an in-flow child of a flex container.

Note this means a contiguous run of text can be wrapped inside an anonymous flex item which do not correspond to any element, and an element child of a flex container might not be a flex item if any of the following

- It is [absolutely positioned](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

  > an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout.
- It has [`display: contents`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents)

  > The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
  >   pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of
  >   box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had
  >   been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document
  >   tree.

  Its children will become the flex items instead (unless something from this list applies to them).
- It has [`display: none`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-none)

  > The element and its descendants generates no boxes.
- It has [`box-suppress: discard`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-box-suppress-discard)

  > The element generates no boxes at all.
- It has [`box-suppress: hide`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-box-suppress-hide)

  > The element generates boxes as normal, but those boxes do not
  >   participate in layout in any way, and must not be displayed.
- Previously, if a child of a flex container had a `display` value that generated an anonymous parent, that parent became the flex item instead of the child. This changed and now the child becomes the flex item, and no parent is generated.

Apart from that, yes, the `display` value should not prevent an element from being a flex item.

Be aware that flex items are [blockified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#blockify), so for example `inline-block` becomes `block`, `inline-table` becomes `table`, `inline-flex` becomes `flex`, etc.

This means that, whatever the specified [outer display role](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#outer-role), the flex item will always be block-level.

Basically, the `display` property, when used on a flex item, is only useful to set its [inner display layout model](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inner-model), e.g. that you want the flex item to be a flex container for its contents.

> A [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) establishes a new formatting context for its
>   contents. The type of this formatting context is determined by its
>   [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) value, as usual. However, flex items themselves are
>   *flex-level* boxes, not block-level boxes: they participate in their container’s flex formatting context, not in a block formatting
>   context.

(The terminology differs a bit, the Display spec says a flex item is block-level in the sense of its outer display role, the Flexbox spec says it's not block-level in the sense that the formatting context in which it participates is not a block one)