# What is the display mode of children elements inside a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering what is the `display` mode of a child element that is inside a flexbox container.

Is it `inline-block`? Or it doesn't have anything to do with the usual display modes?

```css
  .flexbox {
      display: flex;
    }

    span {
        width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="flexbox">
      <span>child</span>
    </div>
```

**For example**, the child `span` is affected by the `width`, so it isn't `inline` anymore.

I thought about this when I saw a `span` that was being affected by the `width` and it didn't have any `display` set, according to the Chrome inspector. Then I realised that it was inside a flexbox container. But, shouldn't the inspector tell me that the display was changed? (Changed to *what*?, that's the question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are allowed values of the \`display\` property for a flex-item? (layout of flex-item’s children is irrelevant)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261797/what-are-allowed-values-of-the-display-property-for-a-flex-item-layout-of-fl)

Comment: @kukkuz thank you!, I searched but didn't find that question.

Comment: Seems to be `block` in this case, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/ClZDg.png

Answer (score 0):

It's not like `inline-block`, since you cannot align it with `text-align`. Since it's **parent** gets property of `display:flex`, I suggest we could just call it "**flex item**". I agree there should be some indication in the Inspector that this is a flex item, but currently - there is none.