# Making a child of a flex container NOT a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I believe this goes exactly against the way the `display: flex` property is supposed to work, but I wonder if it's possible, or if there's a hack for it.

Is it possible to have a child of a flex container not behave as a flex item? Example:

http://jsbin.com/jusehedumi/edit?html,css,output

Is there any way in which child three could be made behave as a normal display block? Without it automatically aligning due to the `justicity-content: center` of the parent flex container?

A purely css solution would be awesome. Thinking about it, adding some extra HTML would probably make this issue easier to fix/solvable.

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child.three{
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  Is there any way to make child three not behave as a flex child?
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child one"></div>
    <div class="child two"></div>
    <div class="child three"></div>
  </div>
```

*Edit*: I know a child can be taken out of the flex container by using `position: absolute` or the likes. What I'm looking for is a way of making one of the children behave as a `block` element (or `inline` for that matter) while remaining a child of the flex container.

Comment: What do you want to do to that block? Can you override the flex behavior with position: absolute ?

Comment: This is mostly a curiosity question. I had an actual use case but figured it's easier to change the HTML a bit and how I approached the styling rather than break how flex is supposed to work. Still, could be a useful question to other people!

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano Updated my answer. As you can see, there is more than one way to make a flex item behave as a block or inline, though the way to do it depends on what one want to achieve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Updated based on a question edit*

No, there is no property that can be set, to make a flex container child stop being a flex item.

What can be done though, is to not use any flex properties on one, and by that make it behave as a block or inline-block element.

E.g., combined with `flex-wrap: wrap` enabling items to wrap, giving the third item `flex: none` will make it behave as an inline block, giving it `width: 100%` it will behave as a block (as shown below).

When it comes to flex container properties, some can be overridden on the item, like `align-items` / `align-self`, some cannot, like `justify-content`.

To mimic `justify-content` in your given code sample, auto margins could be used, and with that, together with a trick using the `order` property and a pseudo element, one could make the third behave like an inline block:

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child.one{
  margin-left: auto;
}
.child.two{
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex::after{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
}
.child.three{
  background: blue;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
Is there any way to make child three not behave as a flex child?
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child one"></div>
    <div class="child two"></div>
    <div class="child three"></div>
  </div>
```

---

As a note, here is a good answer that describes the flex item's display type:

- [What are allowed values of the `display` property for a flex-item? (layout of flex-item’s children is irrelevant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261797/what-are-allowed-values-of-the-display-property-for-a-flex-item-layout-of-fl)

---

*Initial answer*

> Is it possible to have a child of a flex container not behave as a flex item?

There is no good, cross browser solution to make a flex container child *not* behave as a flex item.

One can use absolute positioning, though as it will take the element out of flow, it won't behave like a block element when it comes to content flow.

> Is there any way in which child three could be made behave as a normal
>   display block?

Based on the fact that a normal block element take a row of its own, filling its parent's width, you can, by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container and give the third item a width of 100%, make it behave like one.

*Note, I also added `align-content: flex-start;` so the items won't stretch/spread along the parent's height, instead align at its top.*

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child.three{
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Is there any way to make child three not behave as a flex child?
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child one"></div>
    <div class="child two"></div>
    <div class="child three"></div>
  </div>
```

---

If you want the third item to keep the same width as the first two, a wrapper could help you.

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child.three{
  background: blue;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Is there any way to make child three not behave as a flex child?
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child one"></div>
    <div class="child two"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="child three"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

If a wrapper can't be used, you could use a right margin, though since percent based margin might render different on different browsers, you need to test it properly, or use another unit, e.g. viewport units, like `vw`.

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child.three{
  background: blue;
  margin-right: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
Is there any way to make child three not behave as a flex child?
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child one"></div>
    <div class="child two"></div>
    <div class="child three"></div>
  </div>
```

---

If neither of the above solutions is an option, the same layout can be achieved using block and inline block elements.

```css
.flex{
  /*  removed the Flexbox properties
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  */
  text-align: center;               /* added  */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child{
  display: inline-block;            /*  added  */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child.three{
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<strike>Is there any way to make child three not behave as a flex child?</strike>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child one"></div>
    <div class="child two"></div>
    <div class="child three"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Only elements that are *in-flow children* of a flex container are flex items.

Therefore, elements that are *absolutely-positioned children* or *descendants beyond the children* of a flex container are not flex items and ignore flex properties.

See my answer here for more details:

- [Absolutely positioned flex item is not removed from the normal flow in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276)

Comment: Right! I knew that, should have made my answer more clear. I meant making a child *behave* as a `block` element even while being inside a flex container.

Comment: Technically, flex items *are* block-level elements, except they exist in a flex formatting context. You should take a step back and explain the primary objective, not what you feel is the path to the solution. Try to avoid the [**XY Problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/300177).